# Dynamically loading components from file - React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm out of ideas so I want to ask you.
I'm trying to readfile and then dynamically render components which was in that file.
For example I'll have MyComponent where I will have all of my Components in a JSON object and when I read the file, it will send through props values I need. This goes fine, but when I want to render a specific object, string received through some async fs library with readfile function isn't accessible in brackets [] and gives me an error.

so its - Loading file component,sending props to abstract component where are all components stored in JSON... when I load const SuperComponent = components[this.props.compType]; and then return it like return() it wont load cause I have promisied string (from file) but when I type in that variable 'MyComponent' by hand it works... but when it loads from file it crashes.... any ideas how to get through it? Need it for my project...

So here I'm reading XML and parsing ( I'm trying to show one component - send to him a function to increase count of processingObject integer and then show next component cause of Array....

```
//Here I'm reading the file and passing prop to abstract component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);

this.state = {
  arrayComponentNames:[],
  currentCompo:0,
}
}
 async readScheme() {

        let file = await RNFS.readFile(this.state.actualScheme, 'utf8');
        let xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(file);
        let scheme = xml.getElementsByTagName('Scheme')[0];
        this.setState({
            SchemeCount: xml.getElementsByTagName('Scheme').length
        });
        let SchemePropertiesLength = scheme.children.length;
        for (let o = 0; o < SchemePropertiesLength; o++) {
            switch (scheme.children[o].name) {
                case 'FirstComp':
                    let oldArray1 = this.state.arrayComponentNames;
                    oldArray1.push(scheme.children[o].value);
                    this.setState({
                        arrayComponentNames: scheme.chidlren[o].value;
                    });
                    break;
                case 'SecondComp':
                    let oldArray2 = this.state.arrayComponentNames;
                    oldArray2.push(scheme.children[o].value);
                    this.setState({
                        arrayComponentNames: scheme.chidlren[o].value;
                    });
                    break;
        }
    }
increase(){
this.setState({currentCompo:this.state.currentCompo+1});
}
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <MyComponent type={this.state.arrayComponentNames} onPressFunc={() => this.increase()}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and here I'm trying to get string from file and send through props to another abstract component which should make a decide which component will be rendered...

```
//Here I'm reading the file and passing prop to abstract component
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Platform,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';
import RNFS from 'react-native-fs';
import xml-parser from 'react-xml-parser';


const components = {
  first:First,
  second:Second,
}
export default class App extends Component {
constructor(props){
super(props);
}
  render() {
    const SuperComponent = components[this.props.type];
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SuperComponent/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Added, any ideas?

Comment: How do you import `MyComponent`, `First` and `Second` component? Did you check if `this.props.type` is not null or undefined?

Comment: Its written in a few minutes just to ilustrate problem...  Sorry for no checking errors.. Its not undefined.. When trying to display that in alert or console.log its okay.. I can also setstate and it displays.... Buď when using it in component object... Not working...

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. How do you import or create `MyComponent`

Comment: import MyComponent from './MyComponent'; at the top of first file where loading xml file...(where are other imports) First and second in MyComponent at the top

Comment: What is the value of `this.props.type`?

Comment: 'first' and 'second'

Comment: If you are importing your component correctly then I don't see any problem with this code.

Comment: Well, problem doesn't appear when i set default state as ['first','second'] statically and then load components... but problem appears when loading names of components from XML file and assign them to props... the next component isn't able to view new component which name was get from XML and assign to it...

Comment: When do you call `readScheme`?

Comment: In componentsDidMount()

Comment: Add this code and try. `{this.props.type === 'first' || this.props.type === 'second' ? <SuperComponent/> : <Text>Loading...</Text>}`